# Starting AutoHotkey GUI min/max/hidden from OUTSIDE the script

Tags: user-interface, window, autohotkey, startup, maximize-window

You can start Windows programs minimized/maximized/hidden from outside the program. For example, from the command-line with `start /max notepad` or by setting the Run field for a shortcut in its Properties dialog. AutoHotkey also supports starting programs min/max/hidden with the `Run` command.

But how can an AutoHotkey script/program that has a GUI support this?

Here's a simple sample script:

```
gui,add,edit,w100 h100
gui,+resize
gui,show
```

Running the script will show a resizable window just big enough for the edit-control.

Running the script with `start /max` or any other method does NOT start it maximized (it doesn't matter if the script is compiled or not, it's the same result).

(Yes, it's possible to manually maximize the window or do it from the script, but that's not the goal. The goal is to have the GUI default to some size, but allow users to override it, like with other Windows programs.)

Does AutoHotkey support `nShowCmd` in `WinMain`? There don't seem to be any `A_` variables that contain it.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be something like this:

```
gui,add,edit,w100 h100
gui,+resize
gui,show

if InStr( A_args[1], "max")
    WinMaximize, A
if InStr( A_args[1], "min")
    WinMinimize, A
if InStr( A_args[1], "hid")
    WinHide, A
```

Then you can:

```
Start script.ahk "maximized"
```

Or

```
Start script.ahk "minimized"
```

Or

```
Start script.ahk "hidden"
```

The argument dont need to be complete, if it contains "max", "min" or "hid" in it, it will work

Comment: Thanks, but "min", "max" etc are not passed to the script, they're passed to AHK itself, so the script does not see those. When `start` or `run` command run `autohotkey.exe`, they set the `nShowCmd` of AHK's `WinMain()`. Yes, I could add support for controlling the window to the script itself, but (1) my script already has command-line arguments, so supporting this would add unnecessary complication, (2) other programs get by just fine without doing this, why shouldn't AHK?